# Add anchored name components dynamically inside a ngFor

Tags: angular, datepicker

I'm developing an Angular 2+ application and I'm trying to generate dynamically as much [Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) as I need (one for each input I will generate in a FormArray).

```
<form [formGroup]="varDataForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
    <div formArrayName="aggLevels"
            *ngFor="let agLevel of varDataForm.get('aggLevels')?.controls; let aggLevelRow = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="aggLevelRow">
            <label>{{agLevel?.get('aggregationLevelName')?.value}}</label>
            <div formArrayName="variableDataForLevel"
                    *ngFor="let vardata of agLevel.get('variableDataForLevel')?.controls; let rowIndex = index;">
                <div [formGroupName]="rowIndex">
                    <select formControlName="variableDataId">
                        <option *ngFor="let gs1 of gs1AIs" [value]="gs1.id">{{gs1.description}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <input formControlName="value" placeholder="Valor" [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker-{{rowIndex}}">
                    <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker-{{rowIndex}}></mat-datepicker>
                    <div class="error" *ngIf="vardata.get('value').hasError('required') && vardata.get('value').touched">
                        Obligatorio
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="deleteRow(aggLevelRow, rowIndex)" [disabled]="disableDelete(aggLevelRow, rowIndex)">Borrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="addRow(aggLevelRow)" [disabled]="disableAdd()">A&ntilde;adir</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button *ngIf="varDataForm.get('aggLevels')?.controls?.length > 0" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="disableSubmit()">Guardar cambios</button>
</form>
```

I have tried to use:

```
<input formControlName="value" placeholder="Valor" [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker-{{rowIndex}}">
<mat-datepicker #myDatepicker-{{rowIndex}}></mat-datepicker>
```

But I get an error:

```
NodeInvocationException: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 13 in [myDatepicker-{{rowIndex}}] in ng:///AppModuleShared/VarDataComponent.html@24:59 ("scription}}</option>
</select>
<input formControlName="value" placeholder="Valor" [ERROR ->][matDatepicker]="myDatepicker-{{rowIndex}}">
<mat-datepicker #myDatepicker-{{rowIndex}}></ma"): ng:///AppModuleShared/VarDataComponent.html@24:59
```

But I can't use one  for more than one inputs.

Do you know a way to generate `<mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>` for each `<input formControlName="value" placeholder="Valor" [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker">`?

Comment: it should work fine without having dynamic template reference variable in the iteration, at least when I tried it :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks but I don't know what you have tried. I'm new with Angular and, at this moment, I don't know how to generate a dynamic anchored name and associate it with the input.

Comment: Well that is what I said, that you wouldn't need dynamic template reference variable in this iteration :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srbucd?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Expecting there is no other errors in your code, you wouldn't need to create a dynamic template reference variable, it should work fine within the iteration, so try:

```
<input formControlName="value" [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker">
<mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srbucd?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.html)**